# I want to show and edit list on textbox using one textbox for many times in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

There is 30 textbox on my form. I want to show data from database and if data are more than 30, clear all textbox and show remaining data. And if want to see first 30 data, press page up key. So I used page up key and page down key to see data like page. It still fine on that stage. But,

I met trouble when I change some data on first 30 textbox and press page down key.And press again page up key,at that time all my update data for first 30 textbox can't controlled. I don't know how to control them to able repeatedly press page up key and page down key to see updated data when I edited.I want to update database after all data changes is finished.

Please answered me and so sorry for my English.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear for me. Do you clear textboxes before assigning values to it? and show your code what you've done so far?

Comment: I just want to show, if updated data in first 30 textbox and go another page and went back again,at that time I wanna show data is still remain on that textbox.

Comment: Ok, without your code(_code to display values from db to textboxes_) it's not possible to go further

Comment: Oh my God!.. I already deleted my code.... :'(.. And the problem is not the coding error. I want to know the logic how to control data like filling sign up website eventhough click next button but can click back button and can update data again. How to store data for previous page.

Comment: We need to see code... I suspect you need to look at how to page data from your database. Take a look at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx to see if this helps.

Comment: Thank u so much.. Now it's fine. I can't explain because of my English weakness. Error occur because I can't controlled array well.I'm so sorry for my Bad English. .. :'(

Comment: You  may want to look at using a datasource with a grid instead of 30 textboxes.